# Отображение табличных данных без таблиц

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Всем привет. Есть такой вопрос. Хотел сделать отображение табличных данных из формы без таблицы. Если делать так

```
 <label>Фамилия:</label><p>Surn</p><br />
 <label>Имя:</label><p>Name</p><br />
```

то они отображаются как-то неестественно. Слишком большие расстояния между строками. Таблицу использовать не хочу.
Стили такие:

```
label{
    display:block;
    width:150px;
    float:left;
}
```

Подскажите, чтобы вы поставили заместо `<p>Surn</p>` чтобы она отображалась ровно, как будто там таблица. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если смущает только расстояние между строками, на помощь приходит

```
line-height, padding, margin
```

А вообще, хорошо иногда бывает использовать "CSS RESET" и переопределить все заново.